# How can I add multiple users to a GoodData project through a rest client

Tags: json, gooddata

I am currently using the following syntax to add an individual to a project through a rest client.

```json
{ "user" : {
    "content" : {
        "status":"ENABLED",
        "userRoles":["/gdc/projects/n32w1hmt4if84vrcinsunvo4bo72cj38/roles/4"]
            },
    "links" : {
        "self":"/gdc/account/profile/3c793eb92ca1dcbd8254d9b02cb49ac8"
            }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to add an entire list of people to a project at one time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's unsupported by the API itself. You have to call the API in a loop for every single user you want to add into the project. The solution is to write your own code to do that.
You can also use our Ruby SDK where you can easily use GoodData methods, we already have projectInvitation method implemented.

See this for more details:
http://sdk.gooddata.com/

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Jan